# Consume JSON data through ReactJS

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, rest

I'm new to reactjs and I'm trying to build a simple rest client. I have a json api that I'm using that contains events. However, I'm not sure how to use consume the data because it looks different from the other examples I've seen.

In most examples, the JSON feed looks like this...

{"employees": [{"name":"Laura", "id":"123"},{"name":"Tim", "id":456"}]}

However the json feed that I'm using doesn't have a "employees" : descriptor (or "events" in my case)

Instead my feed looks like this:

[{ "id":"1","title":"event title 1"},{"id":"2", "title":"event title 2"}]

Because of this I'm not sure how to parse the data using the tutorials that I've seen (https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/react-and-spring-data-rest/)

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {employees: []};
}

componentDidMount() {
    client({method: 'GET', path: '/api/employees'}).done(response => {
        this.setState({employees: response.entity._embedded.employees});
    });
}
```

The constructor is initializing the and the setState are starting at the employees descriptor so I'm not sure how to apply this example with my data.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the link you put is about JAVA, totaly different from javascript

Comment: can you log response  before the setState line and give us the content ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your API response contains the list of events you want, so just use `{employees: response}`